# Solve systems of nonlinear equations in R / BlackScholesMerton Model

Tags: r

I am writing my Masters final project in which I am deriving probability of default using Black Scholes Merton Model.I have got stuck in R code. Mathematically, I want to solve this system of nonlinear equations with the package `nleqslv`:

```
library(nleqslv)
T <- 1
D1 <- 20010.75
R <- 0.8516
sigmaS <- .11
SO1 <- 1311.74
fnewton <- function(x){
  y <- numeric(2)
  d1 <- (log(x[1]/D1)+(R+x[2]^2/2)*T)/x[2]*sqrt(T)
  d2 <- d1 - x[2]*sqrt(T)
  y[1] <- SO1 - (x[1]*pnorm(d1) - exp(-R*T)*D1*pnorm(d2))
  y[2] <- sigmaS*SO1 - pnorm(d1)*x[2]*x[1]
  y
}

xstart <- c(1311.74,0.11)
nleqslv(xstart, fnewton, method="Broyden")
# $x
# [1] 1311.74    0.11

# $fvec
# [1] 1311.7400  144.2914

# $termcd
# [1] 6

# $message
# [1] "Jacobian is singular (see allowSingular option)"

# $scalex
# [1] 1 1

# $nfcnt
# [1] 0

# $njcnt
# [1] 1

# $iter
# [1] 1
```

I have tried this with many values of the 5 inputs( stated above that I have computed for 2 companies for different years), but I am not getting the final values of S0 and sigma V.
I am getting message as `"Jacobian is singular (see allowSingular option)"` If I allow singular Jacobean using "control=list(trace=1,allowSingular=TRUE)", then also no answer is displayed. I do not know how to obtain the solution of these 2 variables now.

I really don’t know, what I am doing wrong as I oriented my model on Teterevas slides ( on slide no.5 is her model code), who’s presentation is the first result by googeling
https://www.google.de/search?q=moodys+KMV+in+R&rlz=1C1SVED_enDE401DE401&aq=f&oq=moodys+KMV+in+R&aqs=chrome.0.57.13309j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=distance+to+default+in+R
q=distance+to+default+in+R
Like me, however more successful, she calculates the Distance to Default risk measure via the Black Scholes Merton approach. In this model, the value of equity (usually represented by the market capitalization, > SO1) can be written as a European call option.

The other variables are:

```
x[1]: the variable I want to derive, value of total assets   
x[2]: the variable I want to derive, volatility of total assets    
D1: the book value of debt (19982009)    
R: a riskfree interest rate   
T: is set to 1 year (time)    
sigmaS: estimated (historical) equity volatility
```

Comment: With your values of `xstart` the jacobian consists of all zeros (as `nleqslv` mentions when you use `allowSingular=TRUE`). You can check this with package `numDeriv`.  So your starting values are wrong. I tried `100*xstart` and got a solution without any issues. If you try `xstart <- c(10311.74,0.011)` a solution is found very quickly. So you need to check starting values for being reasonable.

Comment: I would also check the values of `D1, R, ...`. A risk free interest rate of `.8516`? Looks a bit large.

Comment: Dear Bhas, Thanks for your reply. I mistakenly wrote r as .8516 instead of .08516. I will again check rest of the data inputs. While I am taking xstart to be a very large value, I am not getting "Jacobean is singular" as the result and getting an answer. However, could any of my friends, please tell me that can we take the initial unknown variables to be begin with for optimisation as any large value? Will it impact my results since I have to find probability of default for many companies

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the initial values of `SO1` and `sigmaS` as starting values for `nleqslv`.

First of all the R code given by Tetereva doesn't seem quite correct (the variable `Z` should be `D1` as you have named it; similar changes for her `S0` and `D`).
I have modified Tetereva's into this:

```
library(nleqslv)
T <- 1
D1 <- 33404048
R <- 2.32
sigmaS <- .02396919
SO1 <- 4740291  # Ve?
fnewton <- function(x){
  y <- numeric(2)
  d1 <- (log(x[1]/D1)+(R+x[2]^2/2)*T)/x[2]*sqrt(T)
  d2 <- d1 - x[2]*sqrt(T)
  y[1] <- SO1 - (x[1]*pnorm(d1) - exp(-R*T)*D1*pnorm(d2))
  y[2] <- sigmaS*SO1 - pnorm(d1)*x[2]*x[1]
  y
}

xstart <- c(SO1,sigmaS)

nleqslv(xstart, fnewton, method="Broyden",control=list(trace=1)) 
nleqslv(xstart, fnewton, method="Newton",control=list(trace=1))
```

which will give the solution given by Tetereva. (I use `trace=1` here just to check the iteration steps.)

I believe the value you give for `R` should be 8.516 and not something else. Using your values for the parameters

```
T <- 1
D1 <- 20010.75
R <- 8.516  # modified
sigmaS <- .11
SO1 <- 1311.74
```

like this

```
xstart <- c(1311.74,0.11)
nleqslv(xstart, fnewton, method="Broyden")
nleqslv(xstart, fnewton, method="Newton")
```

Then running `nleqslv` with these values converges very quickly.
If one uses `R <- 2.32` (like Tetereva) `nleqslv` will also converge albeit with more iterations.

I cannot help you with what `R` should actually be but from Tetereva's presentation I assume `R` is in percentages. Since I don't have enough knowledge on the Black-Scholes model I can't be of any help for finding out what the correct values are for the various parameters. It's up to you.

Comment: If you read Tetereva carefully then you will see that there is a mistake in the calculation of `d1` and in your version.  The `x[2]*sqrt(T)` should be `x[2]/sqrt(T)`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment. Your contribution to my project is immense. Thanks a lot again. I will try to get it right. I could access internet only today due to certain difficult situation prevailing in my native area.