# R - NLEQSLV LOOP - Bad Results

Tags: r

I am using R - nleqslv package for a Merton Model implementation over ten years and for several companies. My problem is the resulting message: Iteration limit maxit exceeded. At the beginning it was "Jacobian too ill-conditioned", but I overcame it via the "allowSingular" control parameter. 
Here is what I run in R for one of the 60 firms:

```
    library(nleqslv)
    firm.txt<-"Q K r X.E t E0
    1  570397892    0.037368583 0.233290565 0.712328767 87670471 
    2  298421077    0.041952083 0.253988381 0.715068493 95393513 
    3  33869138     0.040477083 0.664630887 0.717808219 48896391 
    4  38419643     0.032099417 0.475755744 0.715068493 56174054 
    5  35286530     0.027812167 0.252814225 0.715068493 53598838 
    6  36801905     0.027028333 0.552871571 0.712328767 42849195 
    7  37798118     0.015626667 0.374539554 0.715068493 62628367 
    8  40594887     0.015787417 0.227146212 0.715068493 82262449 
    9  35638457     0.012659167 0.205291468 0.715068493 75268900 
    10  34889369    0.005081417 0.602946469 0.715068493 80139925"
    firm<-read.table(textConnection(firm.txt),header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    #Loop with solver for 10 dates:
    for(i in 1:10) {
    K<-firm[i,2]
    r<-firm[i,3]
    X.E<-firm[i,4]
    t<-firm[i,5]
    E0<-firm[i,6]
    BS<-function(x){
    f <- rep(NA, length(x))
    f[1] <- (x[1] * pnorm(log (x[1]/K)+(r+( (x[1]^2) / 2) ) * T ) / ( x[2] *sqrt(t))-exp(-r*t)*K*pnorm(log (x[1]/K)+(r-((x[1]^2)/2))*t)/(x[2]*sqrt(t)))-E0
    f[2]<-((x[1]*exp(-t)*pnorm(log (x[1]/K)+(r+((x[1]^2) / 2) ) *t)/( x[2] *sqrt(t))* x[2]) /E0)-X.E
    f
    }
    p0<-c((E0+K),X.E*(V.E/(V.E+K)))
    print(p0)
    ans<-nleqslv(p0,BS,control=list(allowSingular=TRUE))
    print(ans)
    }
```

What has to be add in the nleqslv function?
I really hope you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Where is `V.E` in your problem? As it stands what you present in not reproducible.

Comment: Another question:  what is `T` in the formula for `f[1]` and how is it calculated? In R `T` is shorthand for `TRUE` and should NOT be used. Shouldn't that be `t`?

Comment: Sorry those are mistakes due to tiredness. Correct, T=t and V.E was supposed to be E0. Nevertheless, if I correct for these mistakes, again the message does not change: "Iteration limit exceeded". I really hope there is a way to overcome it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the formulae in your `BS` function are incorrect.
See here [Black Scholes model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model).
Some time ago someone else asked a similar question on Stackoverflow: [Solving nonlinear equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35448997/solve-systems-of-nonlinear-equations-in-r-blackscholesmerton-model/35509490#35509490/Solving%20%60n).
You have also made the formulae unreadable by not using intermediate variables, which makes it almost impossible to analyze and debug.

Write your `BS` function as

```
BS<-function(x){
    f <- rep(NA, length(x))
    d1 <- (log(x[1]/K)+(r+((x[2]^2) / 2) ) * t ) / (x[2]*sqrt(t))
    d2 <- d1 - x[2]*sqrt(t)
    f[1] <- x[1] * pnorm(d1) -exp(-r*t)*K*pnorm(d2)-E0
    f[2]<- ((x[1]*exp(-t)*pnorm(d1)* x[2]) /E0)-X.E
    f
}
```

and correct the assignment to `p0` as follows

```
p0<-c((E0+K),X.E*(E0/(E0+K)))
```

from your comment.

If you use this you get much better results. There are still problems but solving those is up to you.

**Warning: I know nothing about the Black-Scholes model. Only solving non linear equations (sometimes).**

If you use the function `testnslv` in the `nleqslv` package you could investigate if it is possible to find a solution. Function `testnslv` generates a summary for all `global` methods of `nleqslv`.
Like this:

```
for(i in 1:10) {
    K<-firm[i,2]
    r<-firm[i,3]
    X.E<-firm[i,4]
    t<-firm[i,5]
    E0<-firm[i,6]

    BS<-function(x){
        f <- rep(NA, length(x))
        d1 <- (log(x[1]/K)+(r+((x[2]^2) / 2) ) * t ) / (x[2]*sqrt(t))
        d2 <- d1 - x[2]*sqrt(t)
        f[1] <- x[1] * pnorm(d1) -exp(-r*t)*K*pnorm(d2)-E0
        f[2]<- ((x[1]*exp(-t)*pnorm(d1)* x[2]) /E0)-X.E
        f
    }
    p0<-c((E0+K),X.E*(E0/(E0+K)))
    print(p0)
    z <- testnslv(p0,BS,control=list(allowSingular=TRUE))
    print(z)
}
```

and you will see that your system of equations is rather sensitive.
You will have to analyze the results for correct solutions.

**Addendum**

The difficulties you encounter solving your system of equations are caused by very bad scaling of function values.
You can see this by inserting `print(BS(p0))` after the `print(p0)` in the code. You will see that `f[1]` is extremely large compared to `f[2]`.

The solution is very simple: scale the right hand side of `f[1] <- ...` with `K`. In other words divide out `K`.
Then the equation for `f[1]` reads:

```
f[1] <- (x[1]/K) * pnorm(d1) -exp(-r*t)*pnorm(d2)-E0/K
```

Rerun the code with `testnslv` and rejoice. All methods and global strategies find a solution with the norm of function values close to zero.

Comment: Hello Bhas, thanks again for your answer! Yes, by correcting the formula the results get better! However, is it possible to modify the control list in order to improve some of the results from "x-values within xtol" to "function criterion is near zero"?

Comment: See the last addition to my answer. It does not appear to be possible to get rid of all `Xcrit` (shorthand for "x-values within xtol") results. You will have to decide whether the value for `fnorm` is acceptable. In quite a lot of cases the results seem to be ok.

Comment: This was very useful! Thanks a lot, Bhas!

Comment: Hi @Bhas, I have a quick question: is this possible that when I try to compute the result one by one I get terrible solutions? For example that the Jacobian is unuseful?

Comment: Yes. I demonstrated  that in my answer.  For different firm data and different starting values you can get no or invalid results. The model as it stands is just very sensitive. There may be a more robust method but that would need testing; I'm not sure.

Comment: I've added an addendum showing how to get rid of the `Xcrit` results. You have to scale the function value stored in `f[1]`. See the addendum to the original answer.