# nleqslv understand the logic of the iteration procedure

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions

I used the `nleqslv` package to solve a system of two non-linear equations

```
library(nleqslv)
read.table("C:\\Users\\Livia\\Desktop\\firm.txt",header=TRUE)
firm.txt<-"Q K r X.E t E0
"
firm<-read.table(textConnection(firm.txt),header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
firm
#Loop with solver for 9 dates:
for(i in 1:9){
K<-firm[i,2]
r<-firm[i,3]
X.E<-firm[i,4]
t<-firm[i,5]
E0<-firm[i,6]
BS<-function(x){
f<-rep(NA,length(x))
f[1]<-(x[1]*pnorm((log(x[1]/K)+(r+(x[2]^2/2))*t)/(x[2]*sqrt(t)))-exp(-r*t)*K*pnorm((log(x[1]/K)+(r+(x[2]^2/2))*t)/(x[2]*sqrt(t))-x[2]*sqrt(t)))-E0
f[2]<-X.E*E0-pnorm((log(x[1]/K)+(r+(x[2]^2/2))*t)/(x[2]*sqrt(t)))*x[2]*x[1]
f
}
p0<-c((E0+K),X.E*E0/(E0+K))
print(p0)
ans<-nleqslv(p0,BS,control=list(trace=1,allowSingular=TRUE))
print(ans)
}
```

I would really like to understand the logic behind it. 
I have two unknowns and I set their starting values according to

```
p0<-c((E0+K),X.E*E0/(E0+K))
```

How does the iteration procedure works? I already tried to get it from the CRAN packages "nleqslv" 3.0 .pdf but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Hi Livia, welcome to StackOverflow. 2 things -- 1. You can see how this function works by looking at the source code,  2. If you need any more help this is actually a question for our sister site, Cross Validated. stats.stackexchange.com  The source code is available on CRAN, Github, and by running the function in R without `()`

Comment: The algorithms used are not documented in the .pdf. You can find more in the book by Dennis and Schnabel. By the way you presented these equations in [r-nleqslv-loop-bad-results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666061/r-nleqslv-loop-bad-results). Why haven't you used the temporary variables in my answer and why have not scaled `f[1]` with `K`?

Comment: Hi Bhas, I did not receive any notification, so I actually never saw your answer! However, my question is a more theoretical one, I just want to understand the mechanism: system of two equations with two unkowns; set the starting values of these unknowns to start the iteration procedure...and then where are these values substituted in to get more and more results till they converge?

Comment: Given starting values and a jacobian and function values a new set of the unknowns is computed. These are passed to your system which returns the new functions values. Given the return value and a global algorithm a new set of unknowns is computed. This proces is repeated until convergence is reached or when the algorithm used cannot progress. For details see the source code of `nleqslv`. Not documented in `nleqslv.pdf' since that would make the manual much too big. See Dennis and Schnabel (in the References).

Comment: Bhas, does it sound correct to you? "Given a system of two nonlinear equations f[1] and f[2], starting guesses of x[1] and x[2] and a Newton/Broyden methodology, a matrix of first-order derivatives of f[1] and f[2] (Jacobian matrix) is calculated and provides a new set of unknowns after each successful iteration. From each new set of unknowns the same procedure will start again and again until it converges to affine values for x[1] and x[2]."

Comment: Yes but what are "affine values"?

Comment: it means "similar values". I am referring to the convergence of the values of each unknown

Comment: The procedure assumes convergence when the function values are smaller than a prescribed value or when the changes from iteration to iteration of the independent variables are too small. But is does not try to equalize `x[1]` and `x[2]` as your comment seems to imply.

Comment: Sure, I did not mean that, I just explain myself badly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please see my comment above for caveates.

That being said, here's what's happening under the hood when you run that function:

```
> nleqslv
function (x, fn, jac = NULL, ..., method = c("Broyden", "Newton"), 
    global = c("dbldog", "pwldog", "cline", "qline", "gline", 
        "hook", "none"), xscalm = c("fixed", "auto"), jacobian = FALSE, 
    control = list()) 
{
    fn1 <- function(par) fn(par, ...)
    if (is.null(jac)) {
        jacfunc <- NULL
    }
    else {
        if (!is.function(jac)) 
            stop("argument 'jac' is not a function!")
        jacfunc <- function(par) jac(par, ...)
    }
    method <- match.arg(method)
    global <- match.arg(global)
    xscalm <- match.arg(xscalm)
    con <- list(ftol = 1e-08, xtol = 1e-08, btol = 0.001, stepmax = -1, 
        delta = "newton", sigma = 0.5, scalex = rep(1, length(x)), 
        maxit = 150, trace = 0, chkjac = FALSE, cndtol = 1e-12, 
        allowSingular = FALSE, dsub = -1L, dsuper = -1L)
    if (global == "none") 
        con$maxit = 20
    if (length(control)) {
        namc <- names(control)
        if (!is.list(control) || is.null(namc)) 
            stop("'control' argument must be a named list")
        if (!all(namc %in% names(con))) 
            stop("unknown names in control: ", paste(sQuote(namc[!(namc %in% 
                names(con))]), collapse = ", "))
        con[namc] <- control
    }
    tmp <- con[["delta"]]
    if (is.character(tmp)) {
        k <- match(tolower(tmp), c("cauchy", "newton"))
        con[["delta"]] <- as.numeric(-k)
    }
    else if (!is.numeric(tmp)) 
        stop("control[\"delta\"] should be either character or numeric")
    on.exit(.C("deactivatenleq", PACKAGE = "nleqslv"))
    out <- .Call("nleqslv", x, fn1, jacfunc, method, global, 
        xscalm, jacobian, con, new.env(), PACKAGE = "nleqslv")
    out
}
<environment: namespace:nleqslv>
```

If you'd like to see how the other functions work, you can explore them in the same way (type the name of the function and press enter without added the `()`).

If you'd like to do a deeper dive, the full source code is here:

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/nleqslv_3.0.1.tar.gz

and here:

https://github.com/cran/nleqslv

Comment: Hi Hack-R thanks for your answer. However, my question is a more basic one, I just want to understand the mechanism: system of two equations with two unkowns; set the starting values of these unknowns to start the iteration procedure...and then where are these values substituted in to get more and more results till they converge?

Comment: @LiviaG I see. That's definitely a question for stats.stackexchange.com rather than StackOverflow. StackOverflow is a site for when you have bugs in your code and you're trying to figure out how to fix your code.